# An algebra analogous to Lindenbaum algebra

Tags: logic

If we call $\text{Prop}(\mathcal{L})$ the set of all the proposition of a propositional language $\mathcal{L}$ then we can define an equivalence relation on $\text{Prop}(\mathcal{L})$ setting $A \sim B$ iff $A \vdash B$ and $B \vdash A$. The algebra $\text{Prop}(\mathcal{L}) / \sim$ is called Lindenbaum algebra (or Lindembaum-Tarski algebra).

Now let suppose to define an equivalence relation $\dot\sim$ on $\text{Prop}(\mathcal{L})$ setting $A \dot\sim B$ iff $A \vDash B$ and $B \vDash A$, obtaining an algebra $\text{Prop}(\mathcal{L})/\dot\sim$.

Is the algebra $\text{Prop}(\mathcal{L})/\dot\sim$ an algebra with a particular name? What about the relation between $\text{Prop}(\mathcal{L}) / \sim$ and $\text{Prop}(\mathcal{L})/\dot\sim$?

Comment: Assuming you are talking about ordinary propositional logic, then $\vdash$ and $\vDash$ are equivalent...

Comment: I suppose you have assumed the completeness theorem...so the second algebra is exactly the Lindenbaum algebra right?

Comment: How are you defining $\vdash$ and $\models$ here? I have seen $\vdash$ used to refer to a consequence relation and not a specific proof calculus in *Algebraizable Logics* by Blok and Pigozzi, for example.